# Enter Javascript Form on webpage using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Source code:

```
<TD VALIGN="BOTTOM" HEIGHT="24"><A HREF="javascript:processSearchForm
(document.frmSearchForm)"><IMG SRC="/RDPANN/pbs/images/funcsearch.gif" BORDER="0" 
WIDTH="68" HEIGHT="18"></A></TD>
```

I am trying to submit a form on a website using the code listed above.  The search function on the website seems to have an image listed as the search button and I cannot figure out what the ID of the search function is.

Comment: There isn't an id or name. An alternative is to getelementsbyTagName("A") to get all of the links for the element and then loop that collection and match either the href, src or some match on the outerhtml. Or you could fire the javascript directly using `.execScript`

Comment: can you provide a link to the web page?

Comment: @ooo could you elaborate on the different options you listed?  Also which do you think would be the easier way?

Comment: @ron I could post the website but you must have specific access to it in order to access it.  If you would like I can send a screen shot and the source code.

Comment: @ooo
I was able to figure it out using the .exeScript method you listed, thanks.